# Twilio Processes '&' as "And'

Tags: twilio

Just noticed Twilio processes '&' as 'and' when it sends a text. We prebuild questions and have limit of 160 so we use '&' instead of 'and' to have more space. But when the text is sent it gets cut off because Twilio processes it as "and". Anyone have this issue?

Comment: Hi, Twilio developer evangelist here. Can you tell me which programming language you're using for this? I have just tried with C# and JavaScript and the ampersand character did not get replaced

Comment: We use python. We've tried so many options and ideas and no success.

Comment: Marcos, I am having a similar issue using PHP Helper App.  When using Twilio/Twiml class it appears that Attributes have the "&" replaced.   I am trying to append variables to a URL string and to be used by the CallBack. and the '&" are all escaped.      $response->record(
    array(
      'action' => $action , 
      'maxLength' => '120'
     )                                                                                 $action = "test.php?name=value&name2=value2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, to create TwiML, should use the twiml helper lib, it will escape special characters in message with right xml encode

```
from twilio import twiml
r = twiml.Response()
r.message(msg=body, to=to_number,sender=from_number)
xml = str(r)
```

More reference, https://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/twiml.html

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not a Python developer, but I have just tried sending an SMS using Python (done it using JS and C# as well as per mi comment above) and successfully got an SMS message that had an ampersand in it.

I've followed the documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/sending-via-rest).

My code is as follows:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

client = TwilioRestClient("ACXXXXXXXX","0XXXXXXX")

client.messages.create(to="+44XXXXX",
                     from_="+44XXXXX",
                     body='Testing & checking')
```

Now, as you will see, I've used two UK numbers to send and receive the SMS messages. I can't quite tell from your profile where you're trying to send the messages to & from, but Twilio gives the message as is to the carrier, and I;m thinking there is a chance the carriers themselves are replacing the `&` with `and`, but don't really know how to prove that.

One way to check it is by maybe buying another Twilio number (from another location thus using another carrier), and trying to send your message again.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks my friend. We are using us numbers and have tried on 2 different carriers with 7 different numbers. I'm guessing it is just how twilio processes it.

Comment: This is the weirdest thing, because I can't see that behaviour. I'd suggest getting in touch with help@twilio.com, and they will be able to trace your requests to see exactly where this is happening.

Comment: @MarcosPlacona we are using TwiML, in the XML response, we have "&" in body and it cause twilio return error message "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.". Any idea on how to encode/escape the "&"? We're not using the Rest api

Comment: TwiML is just XML, so you can encode the `&` character using `&amp;`